# Change Magento 2.3.1 image upload dimensions

Tags: magento2

I changed the `MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH` and `MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT` constants of image uploader in file vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php. But doesn't seem to work. Original image dimension changes. Where else should I change?